# Parsing functions from BASHRC

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm using BASHRC to store alot of my daily routines, and overtime its gotten cluttered, and now there are some duplicate. 
Was wondering if there's a way with SED\AWK\grep to parse all of the functions into array and then remove duplicate.

sample of bashrc with duplicate:

```
  function action1(){
    /usr/bin/operate $1
    }
   function action2(){
    /usr/bin/perform $1 $2
    }
   function action1(){
    /usr/bin/operate $1
    }
```

Thanks,

Roy

Comment: What do you really mean by duplicates, here? Simply that two functions have the same name? What about two functions with the same name that do different things? What about two functions with different names that do the same thing? What about functions that do the same thing, but in different ways? Finding duplicate function names is easy enough. Anything after that may be somewhat ambitious.

Comment: The `function` keyword is helpful for this particular case, but not portable and thus rather useless. A general solution should work even where the explicit keyword is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's REALLY what your input file looks like then all you need is:

```
$ awk '$1=="function"{unq=!seen[$2]++} unq' file
  function action1(){
    /usr/bin/operate $1
    }
   function action2(){
    /usr/bin/perform $1 $2
    }
```

If it's not then edit your question to provide some truly representative sample input and expected output.

Comment: ingeniously crafted, sir